# How to assign default value using url parameter changelist_filters?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

In Django 2.0.6,

I want to assign default model field value when adding the data in Django Admin page.

Here is my code.

## models.py

`class a_model(models.Model):
   a_field = models.foreignKey(~~)
   ~~~~`

## URL (Create page in Admin)

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/~~~/a_model/add/?_changelist_filters=a_field__exact%3D586632`

I want to get 586632 in above url and assign default value to a_field in that page.

I try to this way in models.py

`class a_model(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def default_id(request):
        return 586632`


    `a_field = models.foreignKey(~~,default=default_id.__func__,~~)`

then, I see the default value is 586632 like that I expected.

I want to know how to get the url parameter value to assign default value in model class.

Help me..

Comment: def default_id(request):   (x)   ---->     def default():

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I have the same question and your last comment doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with django admin; Inside the object modeladmin, I've override the '**get_changeform_initial_data**' function in this way:

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    from django.http import QueryDict
    if request.GET.__contains__('_changelist_filters'):
        params = QueryDict(request.GET['_changelist_filters'])
        if 'acto__exact' in params:
            return {'acto' : params['acto__exact'] 
                    }
```

So i get the initial value of the field 'acto' if is specified as a changelist_filter in the url.